# .bss data not fit in allocated RAM size

Tags: c, elf

I am facing below issue during linking time when compiling application.

```
BuildTest/Main.elf section `.bss' will not fit in region `SDRAM_DATA'
../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: region `SDRAM_DATA' overflowed by 2356 bytes
```

Actually application compiled successfully before i have made merging other code with it.

So i have initially tried to find out by comparing old file and new file to check if any huge global or static buffer newly added or not but i haven't found any useful things.  Also merged files is lot (it was taken 15 days to merge), so now it's very difficult to check each and every files.

So is there any way using that i can have information with list of newly global\static buffer added in .bss section?

Note : SDRAM_DATA is memory region defined in linked script.

Comment: When I face this kind of RAM overflows it's usually because I made some changes to some 3rd party API calls. Try and read about any impact your changes have on the API. Usually some APIs define some macros which can dramatically change the size of ram they require depending on the call parameters.

Comment: Have a look here https://mcuoneclipse.com/2013/04/14/text-data-and-bss-code-and-data-size-explained/ and try to use some diff tools to help you

Comment: Basically link your code without any api calls. Check the .bss section in the map file. (Good map files should have a summary of memory used in each section.) Add one library call, check again. Repeat until you find the culprit. You'll also notice if it's several functions slowly building up memory use, or if it is one single function causing it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a linker map generation option to your linker command line.

After running the linker, filter out everything going to .bss from the map file. If you do the same for a build before the merge, then a diff of the two lists should give you an indication which part of the code increased its .bss size.

E.g. for binutils ld the option would be `-Map <name of map file>` or (if using gcc wrapper): `-Wl,-Map,<name of map file>`